# Batch file merge two text files

Tags: cmd.exe

I have two text files and I need to merge them like this:

text file 1

```
[][][]
[][][]
```

text file 2

```
******
******
******
```

output

```
       ******
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
```

I have already looked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097036/merge-two-text-files-line-by-line-using-batch-script
It gave me this:

```
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (1.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in (2.txt) do (
    >>3.txt echo %%a %%b
         )
    )
```

But that script looped until the text was even.
Like this:

```
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
[][][] ******
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly refer to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031687/merge-2-txt-files-in-a-single-tab-delimited-file-in-batch)

I am posting that solution again

```
 @echo off

 set f1=1.txt
 set f2=2.txt
 set "sep=  "  % tab %

 (
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (%f2%) do (
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       set /p line=
       echo(!line!!sep!%%a
      endlocal
   )
 )<%f1%
```